# Resample random variable to fit different variance

Tags: variance, random-variable, data-transformation, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Suppose I have samples drawn from a random variable, and I want to multiply that random variable with a scalar constant. How should I transform the samples such that they would have been drawn from that scaled random variable?

For a normally distributed variable, I can just do:

```
def transform_normal_samples(samples, multiplier):
    var = np.var(samples)
    sigma = np.sqrt(var)
    mean = np.mean(samples)

    new_var = var * multiplier
    new_sigma = np.sqrt(new_var)

    return (samples - mean) * new_sigma / sigma + mean * multiplier
```

because I know that for $X = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ and constant $c$: $cX = \mathcal{N}(c\mu, \sqrt{c\sigma^2})$.

In general, I believe the mean of the distribution is always scaled by $c$, and the variance by $c^2$. This would mean for the empirical distribution that:
$$
c^2\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \sum_i (y_i-c\bar{x})^2
$$
where $Y = cX$ and I left out the scaling by $1/N$. I don't know how to continue from this to obtain a result for the samples $y_i$.

I also tried estimating the original pdf of the samples empirically, transforming it by scaling the pdf values by $1/c$ and the support by $c$:

```
x, p = ecdf(samples)
p2 = np.linspace(0.00, 1.00, 41)
x2 = np.interp(p2, p, x)
pdf = np.gradient(p2, x2, edge_order=1)
p_new = pdf * (1.0 / multiplier)

x_new = multiplier * x2
p_sum = np.trapz(p_new, x_new)

x2_diff = np.diff(x_new)
p_avg = (p_new[1:] + p_new[0:-1]) / 2.0 / p_sum

areas = x2_diff * p_avg

F_new = np.cumsum(areas)

i_new = np.random.rand(len(samples))
x3 = np.interp(i_new, F_new, x_new[1:])
```

where the function `ecdf` is given by:

```
def ecdf(x):
    xs = np.sort(x)
    ys = np.arange(1, len(xs)+1)/float(len(xs))
    return xs, ys
```

But it seems this approach does not get the transformed distribution just right.

Any ideas? Is this even possible without knowing the original distribution?